# void** pointer and void*[] as function parameters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I'm getting the following warning:
`incompatible pointer types 'void**' and 'int* [2]'`.

When I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void func1(void *arr[]) { }

int main() {
    int *arr[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *(arr[i]) = 5;
    }
    func1(arr);
}
```

Now, it works when I cast arr with `(void**)`, and I couldn't find a reason for that. Furthermore I found that I also need to cast in the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void func1(void **arr) { }

int main() {
    int **arr;
    int i[] = { 1, 2 };
    int j[] = { 3, 4 };
    *arr = i;
    *(arr+1) = j;
    func1(arr); //Doesn't compile unless I use (void*) or (void**) casting
}
```

I know that if a function's parameter is a pointer to `void` we can pass to it whatever pointer we want without casting because all pointers are of the same size then why can't I pass a pointer to a pointer the same way?

Comment: Did you mean `int* arr[5];`?

Comment: Because pointer to a pointer is not a pointer to `void`. Only a pointer to `void` is guaranteed to be compatible with other pointers.

Comment: If pointers were arrays, they would not be called "pointers".

Comment: Pointers are not pointer-to-pointers. Pointer-to-pointers are not arrays, nor are they multi-dimensional arrays, nor can they point at them. And that's that...

Comment: Maybe if you explain what the code is supposed to do, we can make a suggestion how to best fix it.

Comment: Why the mystery? The types are not compatible. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All object pointer types, including `int *`, are guaranteed to be *interconvertible* with `void *`, but they are not *interchangeable*.  The representation of type `int *` does not have to be the same as the representation of type `void *` (though in practice, it almost always is), so there is no automatic conversion from a pointer to `int *` (i.e. `int **`) to a pointer to `void *` (i.e. `void **`).  It is not safe to assume that a pointed-to thing of one type can be correctly re-interpreted as a thing of the other pointed-to type.

Note, by the way, that this:

> if a function's parameter is a pointer to void we can pass to it whatever pointer we want without casting because all pointers are of the same size

is an incorrect characterization.  Pointers are *not* required to all be the same size.  It is required only that every object pointer can be *converted* to type `void *` and back, and that the result of such a round-trip conversion is equal to the original pointer.

Do take @Lundin's comments to heart: arrays are not pointers.  Nevertheless, values of array type do *decay* to pointers under most circumstances, including when they appear as function arguments or as the right-hand operand of an assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your second code snippet:

```
void func1(void** arr) { }
int main() {
    int** arr;
    int i[] = {1,2};
    int j[] = {3,4};
    *arr = i;
    *(arr+1) = j;
    func1(arr); //Doesn't compile unless I use (void*) or (void**) casting
}
```

You never initialize `arr` to point to a pointer or an array of pointers to `int`.  It is uninitialized, so its value can be anything.  When you set `*arr` to `i`, you invoke undefined behavior.

Furthermore, `int **` and `void **` are not interoperable types, you cannot convert one to the other implicitly.  The rationale for this is that on some rare systems, `int *` and `void *` may have a different representation.  Casting a pointer to `int *` as a pointer to `void *` would be as incorrect as casting a pointer to `float` as a pointer to `double`.  On systems where the representation is the same, you can just write the explicit cast.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void func1(void **arr) { }

int main(void) {
    int *int_pointer_array[2];
    int **arr = &int_pointer_array;
    int i[] = { 1, 2 };
    int j[] = { 3, 4 };
    *arr = i;     /* this line modifies int_pointer_array[0] */
    *(arr+1) = j; /* this line modifies int_pointer_array[1] */
    func1((void **)arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "corrected version" still causes undefined behaviour even if the pointer types had the same size and representation. It also violates the strict aliasing rule  (`int *` is aliased as `void *`)

Comment: @M.M: it does, but in separate functions, unlikely to cause a problem if the representation of `int *` and `void *` are the same.